# Hiding base class member

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class and a derived class.  I am calling a function in the base class (that has lots of code I want to reuse) and it references a private variable that I want to hide in the derived class.  That is to say, I want to call the baseclass method and have it act on the derived class member variable.  The private members are different types but are derived from the same type.  When I call the protected function, it refers to the base class private member, rather than the derived class member.  I don't want this.  Rather, I want to call the baseclass method and have it refers  to the derived class member. How would I define everything to achieve what I want?

```
   public class Base
   {
       private Thing aThing;
       public base(){}

       protected doSomething()
       {
            Print( aThing.aMmebr)
        } 

    } 


    public class Deriv:Base
    {
       private AnotherThing aThing;

       public void DoIt()
        {
               doSomething ()

         }
    }
```

I want to call the baseclass function doSomething and I want it to print aMember of AnotherThing.

Comment: Seriously: if you're writing C#: please use C# keywords - it is very vexing to have to change all the cases to work a demo

Comment: Make `aThing` `protected` in your base-class and completely omit it in your derived one. You can even stay on `private`, as you don´t seem to do anything with that member in your derived class.

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell please use .Net keywords if you write .Net. Make your aThing protected or public in your base class.

Comment: You should definitly have a look at inheritance and access-modifiers in .NET.

Comment: If AnotherThing is derived from Thing - then it may not be necessary to define aThing in Deriv. - You can assign a derived class to a base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `Base` is going to be typed in IL to use whatever `aThing` is typed as - so: `Thing`. You *can* use `virtual` in a property such as `protected virtual aThing {get; set; }` such that `Deriv` can `override` that property to replace it with a different *value/implementation*, but: you can't change type in an `override` - it would still need to be `Thing`. It could be a *subclass* of `Thing`, though - so if `AnotherThing : Thing` that could work.

However, it sounds like you should really make your entire `doSomething` method `protected virtual`, and have the derived class `override` *that* instead. Something like:

```
public class Base
{
    private Thing aThing;
    public Base() { }

    protected virtual void doSomething()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(aThing.aMmebr);
    }
}


public class Deriv : Base
{
    private AnotherThing anotherThing;

    protected override void doSomething()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(anotherThing.aMmebr);
    }
    public void DoIt()
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: would composition rather than inheritance be another good option?

Comment: Hi Marc, I need to use the code in doSomething in the base.  The actual example has lots of code I want to reuse and aThing shows up all over the place.  I don't want to override doSomething,  I want to call it.

Comment: If you own Thing and AnotherThing, I think extracting an interface containing aMember and having Thing and AnotherThing implement it is a better approach (see my answer), if you do not own those classes, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use virtual and override properties for aThing.

```
public interface IHasString
{
    string aMember { get; }
}

public class Base
{
    protected virtual IHasString aThing { get; set; }

    public Base(){}

   protected void doSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aThing.aMember);
    }

}


public class Deriv : Base
{
   protected override IHasString aThing { get; set; }

   public void DoIt()
    {
        doSomething();

     }
}
```

Comment: The type of property is not a `string` in OP question

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated it. It's implied that Thing and AnotherThing both contain a string property named 'aMember'.